# SQL query from relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL - Users and Songs. I have a relationship - **UsersSongs**.

How can I write a SQL query to display a pair - "**User.name - Song.name**". Those. I want to output every song of all users. If the user has no songs, then the user should still be highlighted.

```
select u.email from users u
inner join users_songs us on u.id = us.user_id
```

I can to output just user name. How can I add the song name to this query?

How to do it on Entity Framework is clear, but I don't know how to do it on SQL.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `select u.email, us.name` followed by your current query.

Comment: It doesn't work. I need something like - select u.email, song.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the user and song tables via the junction table:

```sql
SELECT u.email, COALESCE(s.name, 'NA') AS song_name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_songs us
    ON u.id = us.user_id
LEFT JOIN songs s
    ON s.id = us.song_id;
```

The above logic joins through using left joins, to ensure that users having no songs are not dropped from the query.  For such users, their since record would display `NA` for the song name.